# Is there a way to create a web.config transform given a source file and a target file?

Tags: c#, web.config-transform

I've a source `web.config` file and a target `web.config` file that has been hand-edited for my production environment.

Is there a utility, tool or method to *automatically* create a web config transform between the two files?

Comment: Why would you want to generate something you already have produced?

Comment: I didn't do the hand-edited version, another engineer put that together. We now want to automate the deployment so I'd like a simple way to reverse-engineer the changes back to a Web config transform.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this post:

[Generating xml document transformation for Staging and Production web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231040/generating-xml-document-transformation-for-staging-and-production-web-config-fil)

The accepted answer points to a piece of software that he wrote:

https://github.com/CameronWills/FatAntelope

Seems to work well..